# Testing In App Purchase for iOS / MacOS X and two-factor authentication for test accounts

Tags: ios, swift, macos, in-app-purchase, itunes

Did anyone recently tested the In App Purchase for iOS and Mac OS X? Apple now started asking for two-factor authentication for test accounts created in iTunes Connect.
My issue is whenever I try to call

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

to restore purchases or make

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

to make purchase, I am asked for authentication with window "Sign in with Apple ID".
I enter login and password of the test user, freshly created in iTunes Connect.
For emulator after entering them, I get

[image: apple id verification]

After clicking Settings, I am just sent to Settings without any attempt for second factor auth. But I get the SMS with 6-digits code :)
One one of real iPhones I see second factor but after entering 6 digits, nothing happens. Another real iPhone also just nothing for the second factor, I only see Settings and it's all.

Similar problem for Mac OS X.
I am asked to enter login, then password, then 6 digits for the second factor.
After all I get the

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) { ... }
```

called with Error "Authentication failed".
For purchase I get updatedTransactions / failed.
Did anyone had similar issues recently, is it yet another Apple's bug with this two-factor of it's just me, doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Testing in-app purchase has never been realistic. You've never been able to see and pass through the actual system dialogs that the user sees. So as long as you are able to perform the purchase, just laugh uproariously and move on.

If you are not able to perform the purchase at all, abandon this approach, and instead, build for TestFlight and act as a tester, so you are not using the test user. You will be able to perform the purchase as your real user, and so the two-factor authentication will succeed.

Also, new in Xcode 12 (still in beta), you can test in-app purchase without networking. Again, you won't see all the dialogs a real user will see, but at least you can test the *functionality* of your Store Kit-related code.

Comment: matt, thank you very much for your answer. I will try TestFlight tomorrow and will try installing the XCode 12. I don't want any realistic things, I want it all just work at least somehow in any way :) It was working fine previously for iOS, but now my apps get rejected and I can't event test them :)

Comment: Is TestFlight available for Mac? As far as I understand, it's not.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the question did say iOS.

Comment: I have similar auth problem for both platforms, ios and osx. That's crazyness.